# Who are the statues at the Gates of Argonath?

Tags: character, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

In Lord Of the Rings, when paddling down the river Anduin the fellowship pass by two statues, one on each side of the river, both holding their left hand forward. One is in armour and is bearded and carries a sword. The other is cloaked. Aragorn calls them "the Kings of old" but do we actually know which kings they are? They looked to me a lot like Elendil and Isildur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's Argonath you are talking about. Also known as The Gates of Argonath or The Pillars of Kings. The names of they are Isildur and Anárion.

**Isildur** was the High King of Gondor and Arnor. He also cut the One Ring from Sauron's hand.
**Anárion** is the brother of Isildur. Both ruled together a part of Gondor.

> The Argonath, also known as The Gates of Argonath or The Pillars of Kings, is a monument comprising two enormous statues carved in the likenesses of Isildur and Anárion, standing upon either side of the River Anduin at the northern approach to Nen Hithoel. It marked the northern border of Gondor, as nearby down south were previous outposts, the Amon Hen and the Amon Lhaw.

More information can be found for example [here](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Argonath) or [here](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Argonath). Or you google 'lord of the rings two statues'. It was not hard to find ;-)

One another important thing:

> Unlike in the book, in the movie the Argonath appears to portray Isildur and his father Elendil (shown holding a sword, not an axe, as portrayed during the film's prologue)

[image: The Gates of Argonath]